# SVG <circle> fill covering previous circle

Tags: css, svg, fill

I'm building an svg circular progress graph.

I'm trying to style my svg's stroke to match the visible part of circle.center but when I change the stroke of circle.progress it does not shrink the circle's fill enough to show the black part of circle.progress and match the width of the actual progress bar.

```
<svg width="300" height="300">
    <circle class="progress" id="progress-radial-1" r="125"/>
    <circle class="center" r="140" cx="140" cy="140" />
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="150" y="185" />
</svg>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BenRacicot/2kc7c56j/

Here is the svg's outcome (left): 
[image]
I'm trying to get the results on the right. As you can see the circle.center which controls the blue progress bar (at 50%) also has a fill which is white in the image (gray in fiddle) and covers the black svg stroke too much. I need that stroke to be the same width of the blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`center` and `progress` circle has different origin and should have the same (now set to 150).

The `center` has now 25px smaller radius than `progress`, to fit inside its stroke.

So if you update the markup like this, change the fill for `center` to `#ddd` and change the `svg` background to `#000` you will get the layout you want

```
<div class="pie-wrapper">
  <svg width="300" height="300">
    <circle class="progress" id="pr1" r="125" cx="150" cy="150"/>
    <circle class="center" r="100" cx="150" cy="150" />
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="150" y="175" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kc7c56j/4/)

Stack snippet

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  function radialProgress(update, id){
    let rd = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("r"); 
    let i = 0;
    let a = 0;
    let x = rd * 2 * Math.PI;
    i = update;
    a = i / 100;
    let p = x * a;

    jQuery(".progress").attr("stroke-dasharray", p + ", " + x);
    jQuery(".progress").attr("stroke", "#0065a4");
    jQuery("text").text(update + "%");
  }

  radialProgress(50, 'pr1');
})
```

```css
.pie-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
    .pie-wrapper svg {
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

.progress {
    stroke-width: 50;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.center {
    fill: #ddd;
}

text {
    fill: #fff;
    font-family: 'Share Tech Mono';
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="pie-wrapper">
  <svg width="300" height="300">
    <circle class="progress" id="pr1" r="125" cx="150" cy="150"/>
    <circle class="center" r="100" cx="150" cy="150" />
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="150" y="175" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

*Note, it is the `progress` circle which controls the blue progress bar (at 50%), not the `center`, and the black `svg` doesn't have a stroke, it has (had) only a dark gray background.*

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer @LGSon . However if you see my fiddle again (updated) it seems that the SVG #333 is still half the width of whatever is the full black section. (Still can't understand what's controlling it) I was hoping to put gradients in if possible so having them aligned correctly is needed I'm assuming.

Comment: @BenRacicot The stroke's width span half way into the circle, half outside, so the center of stroke's width is at the circle's edge

Comment: @BenRacicot Add your gradients and if they misbehave, send me a note here and I'll have a look

Comment: @BenRacicot If you check this fiddle, where I removed all but the `progress` circle, [https://jsfiddle.net/2kc7c56j/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/2kc7c56j/6/), you'll see how the stroke behave. I filled it with red so it shows what is going on

Comment: @FrankWisniewski I checked, they rotate it differently, though here I solved the stroke issue, rotation issue is new question and answer

Comment: Thanks for the second fiddle. I understand how the red area works but if you take a look at the fiddle I made with the gradient https://jsfiddle.net/BenRacicot/e35gt6bh/ You might be able to see how the black section should not be visible. The gradient section should be double its width. That's the part I'm completely lost about. There isn't even a black style...

Comment: @BenRacicot Add `fill: transparent;` to `progress`...https://jsfiddle.net/e35gt6bh/2/

Comment: Wow, that was it! One last thing. Sizing it smaller/larger. Is that a deep question?

Comment: @BenRacicot You need to recalc your values in the svg/css ... or you can do this `transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0.5);` on `pie-wrapper` ... https://jsfiddle.net/e35gt6bh/4/ .... and bigger with `transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.5);` ... https://jsfiddle.net/e35gt6bh/5/

Comment: @BenRacicot Now I need 2 upvotes and 2 accepts ... :)

Comment: LOLz you earned it. Thank you very much for this. I'll remember your name!